# Button need to be clicked twice to set a right input value angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-router

I tried to make a search system like this

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="search product)" #searchValue/>
<span class="input-group-btn">
  <button class="btn btn-green" [routerLink]="['/search-result']" [queryParams]="{ q: searchValue.value}" >
    <i class="fa fa-search fa-md"></i>
  </button>
</span>
```

Assume than I already write 'Search' in the input tag and then I click the button. The result url

```
/search-result?q=
```

If I clicked again it will give a right url

```
/search-result?q=Search
```

If I change the input value (Search) before I click the button again, example I change it into 'Searching'.
The result is

```
/search-result?q=Search
```

and need to clicked once again to get

```
/search-result?q=Searching
```

So it overdue by one request. Why is this happening? I tried to move the `[routerLink]` to `span` tag but it still the same. Any Idea how to fix it?

Thanks :)

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm having an issue now with my Angular solution!

Comment: @EGC Sorry for late notice. Nope, luckily for me its just an example project which I didn't have to fix